# JQuery Grab Text From Div minus child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an easy way to grab the text from this div with out getting any child elements?

```
<div id="someselector">
   <strong>Title Text Unwanted</strong> This is the text I need
</div>
```

I know I probably could do a substring on the strong.  I was just wondering if there was a function that could automatically do it for me in jQuery
  like:

```
 $('#someselector').html().not('strong').text()
```

Comment: `$('#someselector')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically boils down to this:

```
$("#someselector").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

First, you clone the element, get its children, remove them and then get the text of the clone.

Comment: This works thanks,  I'll accept this as the answer when the time constraint is done from stack