# how to select one single text from multiple text inside html tags with css selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<span class="filter-dot hidden"></span>
Brand <span class="filter-count hidden">(0)</span>
<input type="hidden" class="js-filter-count" value="0">
<span class="filter-clear hidden" data-displaytype="checkBox">
Clear
</span>
```

I want to select only 'Brand',but when i'm using `$('div.filter-type-name').text();` it selects 'Brand' as well as 'Clear'. Can anyone please suggest me how can I select 'Brand' only?

Comment: your code is not matching with your statement

Comment: As per your code snippet $('div.filter-type-name').text(); will return nothing

Comment: Wrap Brand into one more span and select this span only.

Comment: You have no `div` with a class `.filter-type-name`.

Comment: i'm sorry guys actually the code starts with <div class="filter-type-name lfloat"> and then what written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap "Brand" into one more specific selector and select it only:

```
<div class="filter-type-name">
  <span class="filter-dot hidden"></span>
  <span class="filter-name">Brand</span>
  <span class="filter-count hidden">(0)</span>
  <input type="hidden" class="js-filter-count" value="0">
  <span class="filter-clear hidden" data-displaytype="checkBox">Clear</span>
</div>
```

Then:

```
$('div.filter-type-name .filter-name').text()
```

Otherwise, use [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) collection to iterate through it and select what you need (`Node.TEXT_NODE === 3`), but this is not very practical:

```
$('div.filter-type-name')[0].childNodes
```

Comment: I cannot modify the html code actually it is the portion of snapdeal's (mobile listing page url : https://www.snapdeal.com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones?sort=plrty) source code,i'm doing scraping.

Comment: So go with `$('div.filter-type-name')[0].childNodes`. Simple iteration over text nodes will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Either give `Brand` its own surrounding element with a class or id, say "brand-name" and do:

```
$('div.filter-type-name .brand-name').text()
```

or keep it as is and do:

```
$('div.filter-type-name').text().split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

[THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28034793/2562819) seems to solve it.

Here's the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/9dsfbkms/

```
var text = ($(".filter-type-name").clone().children().remove().end().text()).trim();
alert(text);
```

Comment: I cannot modify the html code actually it is the portion of snapdeal's (mobile listing page.url : snapdeal.com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones?sort=plrty) source code,i'm doing scraping.

Comment: sorry. please see my edits above and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Without wrapping your 'Brand' string into a tag. You can use the below method.

Suppose here is your code:

```
<div class="filter-type-name"> 
 <span class="filter-dot hidden"></span>
 Brand 
 <span class="filter-count hidden">(0)</span>
 <input type="hidden" class="js-filter-count" value="0">
 <span class="filter-clear hidden" data-displaytype="checkBox">  Clear </span>
</div>
```

You can use the regular expression match script for checking the text you want.

```
var str = $('div.filter-type-name').text(); 
var res = str.match(/Brand/g);
```

To see the output,

```
<p id="demo"> </p>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```